# Unable to install P4Vasp

Tags: vasp, software-assistance, visualization-software

I am currently learning how to use VASP and was looking at how to get the DOS plots. I have been recommended to use P4VASP but due to some reason I am not able to install it on my Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to use `sudo` to install the said package it says no package p4vasp found. And I think that the older website has also been depreciated http://p4vasp.at/.

Am I required to work with Ubuntu 18.04 only? Or is it somehow possible that p4vasp is no longer working or something. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, everything I tried, and everything tried by several friend always failed.
You can not run p4vasp code on 20.04.
Toomany packages have been abandoned. Welcome to Academia.

Comment: @Cippo1987 what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

The [source code](https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp) is still available on Github, though it hasn't been updated for nearly 4 years. While the project seems to be [abandonded](https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp/issues/22), you should be able to compile from source. I don't suspect the change from Ubuntu 18 to 20 would make it unable to compile, but there probably is not a readily installable version for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6):

The **P4VASP** code is one of the easiest visualization tools for VASP outputs that I have been using. From your question, I understand that your system can't find the p4vasp executable file which can be solved by adding its path to the `.bashrc` file in the home folder. However, there are a lot of visualization tools that offer higher quality and more control of VASP output plots. I recommend using [VASPKIT](https://vaspkit.com/) to extract data from VASP outputs, and then you can use **XMGRACE** or **GNUPLOT** to plot the graphs. You can check this [website](http://molphys.org/gnuplot_tutorial/dos_plot.html) that contains some **GNUPLOT** scripts for high-quality DOS plots. I recommend also checking this [thread](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-are-some-good-band-structure-dos-plotting-tools-styles/2219#2219) which I believe will be very useful for you.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding their post, they seem to have an issue even installing p4vasp, rather than accessing it after installation.

Comment: I think it might be related to the python version.

Answer (score 4):

py4vasp is also used as an interface for VASP. You can install p4vasp by using pip `pip install py4vasp`
Please check [p4vasp](https://vasp.at/py4vasp/latest/) for more detail.

Comment: Note, [p4vasp](https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp) is a different program than [py4vasp](https://github.com/vasp-dev/py4vasp). While the developer of p4 has contributed to py4 at least once, they have largely been developed separately and p4 seems to be defunct.

Comment: Corrected! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to manually install p4vasp on higher version of ubuntu, I have tested on ubuntu 20.04.
The step wise manual for installation
https://github.com/HaoyuYang59/p4vasp/blob/master/README.Ubuntu